# How can I get the value of my role using this query

Tags: session, laravel-5, authentication, session-variables

I am having an error... I don't know how to fix this...

I am doing something that will set page privileges to admin employee and other roles.

But suddenly I doesn't get the value of my variable role.

[image]

```
 public function login(Request $req)
     {
        $username=$req->input('email');
        $password=$req->input('password');
        $breadcrumb = 'Dashboard';
        $pageTitle = 'CollabUX | Dashboard';
        $prepath ='../';
        $currentURL = Req::url();

        $user = DB::table('add_users')->where(['username'=>$username,'password'=>$password])->get();

        if(count($user)>0){
            session(['isloggedin' => 'true']);
            session(['roles' => $user->role]);

        return View::make('dashboard')->with(
            array('breadcrumb' => $breadcrumb,'pageTitle' => $pageTitle,'currentURL' => $currentURL,'prepath' => $prepath));
        }
        else{
            //redirect page
            $data = array(
                'error' => 1,
                'remarks' => 'Invalid Username/Password. Please try again.'
                );
            return View::make('login')->with('data', $data);


        }       
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two solutions.

You can define a user in code as admin

or you can create a separate table

```
userroles (id, title)
```

then you have to check with your requirements.

if only one user can have only role

then add `userrole_id` in `users` table and update accordingly.

if one user can have multiple roles

then create a separate table

```
users_to_userroles (id, user_id, userrole_id)
```

and it will be a pivot table.

Comment: is their other way? without using pivot table?

Comment: Then you can define in code that userId = 1 is admin.

Comment: can you show some example? im sorry im new to laravel.

Comment: Follow these steps : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/user-admin-authentication

Comment: i followed the steps but its giving me an major error